# Why are these block appearinng

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

a was making an explosion , but when i was preparing the material for the volume , the volumes emission strength is needed to be increased , so i did that but these blocks of bright emission appear

[image: EmissionBlocks]

Comment: Try using cycles

Comment: tried , still there